# Sharing session variables between Vaadin and embedded applications

Tags: embed, session-variables, vaadin

I have a Vaadin v6 application that uses the embed component to show a JSP page from another application (JPivot, in this case). Both applications are running in the same application server (Tomcat). I need both applications to communicate and I'm trying to do this by using session attributes. However, each application has its own session and so one is ignorant of the other attributes. My question is how to make these applications communicate without using a database or an external file? It can be other solution than session attributes.

Comment: Use some sort of MQ between both application? Is it a requiring a high bandwidth? Are they in the same WAR file?

Comment: No for all the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wish to do is either IPC between two web apps,
or sharing some informations between them.

If you have a cache available (memcached or similar) you could
store/retrieve the information there.

If no cache is available, then CrossContext=true might help you.
With this you can call "the other" webapp from inside the servlet/request.

Here is a simple explanation how this works

http://lukaszbudnik.blogspot.ch/2009/06/session-sharing-in-apache-tomcat.html

If you google for "tomcat session sharing" you will get many more results.

Please note that this CrossContext stuff only works as long as they are in the same tomcat instance.
As soon as you add another tomcat instance for load balancing or high availability this will break. In that case you should use some sort of message bus or message queue.